# Wordpress media files management

Tags: wordpress, permissions, media

I'm working on a site that provide content (video, pdf, ppt ...) to users via subscription.

- I create a custom post type , each post of this custom post type (called Content) will have an URL to the file according to that post.
- Each Content will belong to a category (taxonomy) , and one of these categories will be Free to view for both anonymous and logged in user. All categories that weren't marked as Free will need to pay for subscription to view.

Anyone can provide solution for me ? Much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your description, you want to limit your user.
you can use Restrict Content Plugin ( [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/) ) to do that.